# TeamCity SoapUI Integration

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, teamcity, soapui

I am new to teamcity and need some help in setting up the parameterized build.We are using jenkins to run regression project written in SoapUI and through paramiterized build options we are able to pass parameter(such as test environment,mercurial banch it has to pool the changes from, test suites in case we have executes only selected ones and tags) to the batch script that executes the testrunnner.bat on command line. How can I do the same stuff in teamcity?

I can see teamcity allows three types of parameters env,system and config.Out of which system parameters are passed to the build script.Can I specify all these required parameters as system parameter?

Also I need to supply these parameters for every build but the values may differ.Does teamcity provides facility same as jenkins that would provide a GUI where I can change these values?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use system properties for required parameters that should be passed inside build script.

To specify what mercurial branches to monitor you can configure [Feature Branches](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Working+with+Feature+Branches).

You can run a build manually in TeamCity and customize needed parameters, see how to [Trigger Custom Build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Triggering+a+Custom+Build#TriggeringaCustomBuild-RunCustomBuilddialog).